# javascript localstorage not disabling the button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web page to display the data in a paginated format. I have some sliders in my web page to control the display. So, I have a button which when clicked, will display only those values matching the slider criteria. For this, I have the localstorage to keep the button disabled across all the pages. However, as soon as I navigate to another page, the button gets re-enabled again. This is my code.

```
$("#update").click(function (){
              this.disabled = true;
              localStorage.setItem("updateDisabled", true);
```

And in my jquery where am displaying the updated display, I included the below lines.

```
var disabled = localStorage.getItem("updateDisabled");
            if (disabled) $('#update').attr('disabled', disabled);
            window.console && console.log(masterData,count);
            $(this).toggle(count==masterData.length);
```

What change is needed to keep the button disabled in all the pages?

Comment: what happens if instead of `true` you ask _localStorage_ to remember `'disabled'`?

Comment: Thanks for commenting out. If I keep 'disabled', the button remains active in the subsequent pages, but the OnClick() action is not taking place as expected. Is there a way to keep it disabled across all the pages?

Comment: `1` you haven't included the closing `});` of the click (I assume you just missed it in the copy/paste, you didn't say any errors in console), `2` is the code to look up from _localStorage_ and disable _#update_ being run **before or after** _#update_ exists in the _DOM_?

Comment: The code is to disable the update after the button is clicked. [link](http://omega.uta.edu/~rxv1100/willdoit.php) is the link.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, to make sure the page has finished loading.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (localStorage.getItem("updateDisabled")) {
        $('#update').attr('disabled', true);
    }else {
        $('#update').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. I tried out the suggested option. I still see the button enabled when I go to the next page.

Answer (score 0):

Since localStorage can only save stings, you cannot set boolean value in it. Hence,
Set it as:

```
$("#update").click(function (){ 
this.disabled = true; 
localStorage.setItem("updateDisabled", 'true');
```

And get it as

```
var disabled = localStorage.getItem("updateDisabled"); 
if (disabled=='true') $('#update').attr('disabled', disabled); 
window.console && console.log(masterData,count); 
$(this).toggle(count==masterData.length);
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. I tried out the suggested option. I still see the button enabled when I go to the next page.